# Critical points of a function $f(x,y)$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

So I'm trying to find the critical points of the function given as follows:

$f(x,y)=2x^3-3x^2y-y^3+6y$

The partial derivatives are then:

(1) $D_1 f(x,y) = 6x^2-6yx$

(2) $D_2f(x,y) = -3x^2-3y^2+6$

Setting (1) $=0$ and solving, I find $x=y$.

Setting (2) $=0$ and solving, I find the solutions $(\pm \sqrt{2}, 0),(0,\pm \sqrt{2})$

Now, initially I didn't think carefully and assumed these to be the four solutions I was searching for.

Then I figured it couldn't be the case before as we already established from (1) that $x=y$ which isn't the case for any of my solutions.

And just by observation from (2) I can see $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$ are valid solutions which also satisfy $x=y$.

However the main question asks for 4 critical points so I am at a loss on how to continue further.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=critical+points+f(x,y)%3D2x%5E3%E2%88%923x%5E2y%E2%88%92y%5E3%2B6y) to show us what solutions we are aiming for

Comment: @lioness99a Yes I did use it and the solutions are $(\pm1,\pm1),(0,\pm \sqrt{2})$. However, the last two confuse me, since it doesn't agree with $x=y$.

Comment: You solved the first equation not carefully. You should get $x=y$ or ??

Comment: @quasi Ah! Or $x=0$ :) That clears everything up, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$f(x,y)=2x^3−3x^2y−y^3+6y$$

As you stated, we have \begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)&=6x^2-6yx\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)&=-3x^2-3y^2+6\end{align}

We can set \begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)&=0\\
6x^2-6yx&=0\\
x^2-yx&=0\\
x(x-y)&=0\end{align}

and conclude that either $x=0$ or $x=y$

We can then set \begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)&=0\\
-3x^2-3y^2+6&=0
\end{align}

Setting $x=0$ gives us \begin{align}
-3\times 0^2-3y^2+6&=0\\
-3y^2+6&=0\\
3y^2&=6\\
y^2&=2\\
y&=\pm\sqrt{2}\end{align}

So we have the solutions $(0,\sqrt{2})$ and $(0,-\sqrt{2})$

We can also set $x=y$ giving us\begin{align}-3x^2-3x^2+6&=0\\
-6x^2+6&=0\\
6x^2&=6\\
x^2&=1\\
x&=\pm 1\end{align}

This gives us the other two solutions: $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ as $x=y$

In conclusion, our solutions are $$(x,y)\in\big\{(0,\sqrt{2}),(0,-\sqrt{2}),(1,1),(-1,-1)\big\}$$